# Ignore 400 error with RCurl

Tags: json, r, curl, rcurl

I have a function which returns the JSON from a long list of URL requests.

A small fraction of these ID's produce 400 errors which in turn stops my Lapply function in R.

Can someone suggest a way to ignore the error message and move on to request the next URL?

```
localisation <- getURLContent(gaiaURL)
localisation <- fromJSON(gaiaURL)
```

Both of these return error messages for certain 'gaiaURL's.

Comment: I think you can wrap the function in `lapply` in a `try()`, like `lapply(df, function(x) try(fromJSON(x)))`. It would be useful if you gave a bit more information on your code and make it reproducible. That way you'll attract accurate answers

Comment: Thanks @KenS. I just managed to fix it actually. I used  return(tryCatch(getURLContent(gaiaURL), error=function(e) NULL))